# Assembly has been downloaded from the web it is flagged by windows as being a web file even if it resides on local computer

Tags: silverlight

I am building a silvelright project using MSBuild command. While building the project through visual studio it is working fine, when I build through MSBuild command giving an error as

> Assembly has been downloaded from the web,it is flaged by widnows as being a web file even   if it resides on local computer.This may prevent it from using in the project . you
>       can change this designation by changing the file properties.only unblock assemblies that  you trust.     [U:\reliability\Implementation\Honeywell.AM.UI\UX\Honeywell.AM.UI.Common\Honeywell.AM.UI.Common.csproj]

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this link?

http://www.mknopf.com/articles/error-this-assembly-may-have-been-downloaded-from-the-web.html

Or this?

http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/this-assembly-may-have-been-downloaded-from-the-web/
For my case I placed it in my project's config file and not on the machine config as this link suggested.

Thanks.